# How to get newlines in classpath for JMSProvider using wsadmin

Tags: wsadmin

I want to create a JMSProvider object with a custom classpath. Here's how I'm doing it in jython:

...
    classpath = "a.jar:b.jar:c.jar".replace(":", "\n")
    properties = [
      ['name', name],
      ['description', description],
      ['classpath', classpath],
      ['externalInitialContextFactory', externalInitialContextFactory],
      ['externalProviderURL', externalProviderURL],
      ['nativepath',[]],
      ['supportsASF','true']
    ]
    AdminConfig.create('JMSProvider', node, properties)
    AdminConfig.save()

The JMSProvider is created, but the classpath variable has the newlines escaped:

```
a.jar\nb.jar\nc.jar
```

How can I tell wsadmin to not escape the newlines?

Comment: How do you get `a.jar\nb.jar\nc.jar` string? Is it a literal string in the config file created by `AdminConfig`?

Comment: The above code created that string. The input `"a.jar:b.jar:c.jar"` comes from Ant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst the WAS admin console (the web page) requires you to enter the classpath with newlines, the wsadmin tool requires that it be separated by the host O/S file separator. So there is no need to modify the input string at all.

```
classpath = "a.jar;b.jar;c.jar"
```

Will work just fine.

Comment: The semicolons are converted into newlines, when opening created object in admin console. Not intuitive, that you must use semicolons in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

`"\n"` is a *real* newline.

Compare `repr(classpath)` immediately after `classpath.replace()` with the `repr(classpath)` that `JMSProvider` sees they should be the same.

Comment: `"\n"` is represented by one byte? That's not how I interpreted the answer in the linked question, but I believe you. Perhaps I need to be sending a windows carriage return, as websphere is running on windows.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with how websphere's AdminConfig object handles the newlines when creating JMSProviders. I'm going to rephrase the question.