# Why is new line "\n" not working for Jython for WAS wasadmin

Tags: python, linux, jython, rhel, wsadmin

For a jython script for wsadmin... I am doing

```
CLASSPATH = "/path/jar1.jar" + "\n" + "/path/jar2.jar"
```

But its not working, it setting as `/path/jar1.jar/path/jar2.jar`

Where am I going wrong.

Comment: note also that websphere documentation explicitly recommend avoiding `\n`: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fcxml_jython.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use path separator ([`os.pathsep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pathsep)) instead of newline:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.pathsep.join(["/path/jar1.jar", "/path/jar2.jar"])
'/path/jar1.jar:/path/jar2.jar'
```

Comment: But in websphere path name are supposed to be separated by line break not :     `In the native path list box, browse or add a path which forms the location for the resource provider native libraries. Native path entries are separated by using the ENTER key and must not contain path separator characters (such as ';' or ':'). Native paths can contain variable (symbolic) names which you can substitute using a variable map.`

Comment: @DebajyotiDas, What if you hardcode `CLASSPATH=/path/jar1.jar:/path/jar2.jar` ? (`CLASSPATH=/path/jar1.jar;/path/jar2.jar` if you're using Windows)

Comment: Turns out WAS will auto convert `;` to newlines. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @DebajyotiDas, classpaths should be separated by `:` in unix.

Answer (score 0):

**Working**:

Whilst the WAS admin console (the web page) requires you to enter the classpath with newlines, the wsadmin tool requires that it be separated by the host O/S file separator. So there is no need to modify the input string at all.

```
classpath = "a.jar;b.jar;c.jar"
```

Will work just fine.

**Source**: 
[How to get newlines in classpath for JMSProvider using wsadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516038/how-to-get-newlines-in-classpath-for-jmsprovider-using-wsadmin)